# Clarification on squaring residuals

Tags: math, statistics, regression

I understand we take squares of residuals because it penalizes large deviations from actuals more than smaller ones, but how does that help? We try to minimize sum of squared residuals anyways, so why does it matter if one of the predictions is more penalized vs others?

Comment: Both are used. See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46019/why-squared-residuals-instead-of-absolute-residuals-in-ols-estimation) from stats.stackexchange.

Comment: I know both are used, but I don't see the usefulness in penalizing predictions with large deviations from the actuals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but rather belongs on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and, please, search for duplicates there first.

Comment: [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) and [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) may also be useful. What you're asking is really beyond just the scope of programming -- you're delving into the math behind it. It's by no means a bad question, and I'm certainly curious to hear the answer; this just isn't the right place to ask it.

Comment: Here is my understanding: in the early days of curve fitting, "absolute value" was intellectually abhorrent as it had no derivative for use in the symbolic logic of the calculus. So the square of the errors was used to make the sum of positive numbers, as squaring *does* have a derivative. So squaring all errors make them positive, and adding up all of those now-positive squared errors gives you something  that allowed symbolic logic to be used in deriving the linear algebra for curve fitting in a way impossible if the "absolute value of error" had been used. That is how I understand history.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.